# bz2 data error 7zip

Tags: 7-zip, archiving, utorrent, bz2

I'm using 7zip and I want to unpack archive (link below) of reddit comments for research:
https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/65o7py/updated_reddit_comment_dataset_as_torrents/

Everything past 2005 and 2006.01 gives me data error. And I don't know why. I'm using newest 7zip. No one from people commenting says there are any problems with archive and I rechecked torrent few times (no problems 100%). What's wrong?

I've got 16 GB ram and I use Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and created a ticket so the developer can investigate (https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/2129/ if you're curious).

It doesn't happen with 7zip 16.04, which you can download from https://www.7-zip.org/download.html.

Comment: I also susupected bug in newer versions of 7-zip. Thanks for answer. I'll check your suggestion when I'll return home.

Comment: Yup you're correct 7-zip version 16.04 works fine.

Comment: It may have been a bug in the library that was used to zip those files, and later versions of 7zip stopped supporting those incorrect files.